# AdMob ads not showing in Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, admob, ads

I tried to insert AdMob ads into my application using Google Play Services API
Anyway they're not showing up.

I hope anyone can help me

I have 2 Activity ( MainActivity.java and AdMobAdd.java )

Heres the AdMobAdd.java (If anyone need the MainActivity please let me know)

(I used the Example from here http://kyanogen.com/admob-interstitial-ads/  )

```
package com.myapp.helpme:D;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.rajatbsosz.timbermancheat.R;

public class AdMobAdd extends Activity {

/**
 * Your ad unit id, you must replace it with your actual ad unit id
 * Which you can generate from Admob website
 * 
 */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-99******************";
private static final String TAG = "AdMobAdd";
private InterstitialAd iAd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    iAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    iAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            Toast.makeText(AdMobAdd.this, "Ad loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Failed to load add : "+ getErrorReason(errorCode));
            Log.d(TAG, errorMessage);
            Toast.makeText(AdMobAdd.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    loadInterstitial();
}

public void loadInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("You can add you device id here, run code once and get id from logs")
    .build();

    iAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void showInterstitial() {
    if (iAd.isLoaded()) {
        iAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is not loaded yet");
    }
}

/** 
 * Gets a string error reason from an error code
 * 
 * @param errorCode
 * @return
 */
private String getErrorReason(int errorCode) {

    String errorReason = "unknown error";

    switch(errorCode) {
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            errorReason = "internal error";
            break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
            errorReason = "invalid request";
            break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
            errorReason = "network Error";
            break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
            errorReason = "no fill";
            break;
    }
    return errorReason;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    showInterstitial();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.***.***"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Required permissions for video ads. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|s    mallestScreenSize"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/d3"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.example.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    about 10 TextViews and Buttons...
    ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you declare the view in the Manifest?  Did you give the app the necessary permissions?

Comment: I gave the permission and followed the Google tutorials.

Comment: I post my manifest one moment

Comment: Okay.  But all you have here is your Java.  What does your XML layout look like?  Because you need to have the placeholder there as well as all this Java stuff.

Comment: I assume your log says `"Interstitial ad is not loaded yet"`

Comment: LogCat isnt showing this error

Comment: LogCat isnt even showing anything about my Interstitial ad

Comment: I think my second activity doesnt even get called

Comment: Is it Possible to combine the both Activities?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of banner, here is my example

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity  {

    private Button btnList;
    private AdView adView;
    LinearLayout layout;

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner);

        addBanner();
        // Create the interstitial or big banner
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(Utils.idBANNERBIG);

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d("GAME", "onAdLoaded");
                displayInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Log.d("GAME", errorCode + "");

            }
        });

    }

    // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an
    // interstitial.
    private void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void addBanner() { //small banner
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId(Utils.idBANNER);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        layout.addView(adView);

        // Iniciar una solicitud gen�rica.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

        // Cargar adView con la solicitud de anuncio.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its showing Error "Intersitial cannot be resolved" I changed to intersitialAd but still Error.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** call `showInterstitial()` in `onDestroy()`.

There is no guarantee it will be called and in any case your Activity is already in a partial deconstructed state at that point and the interstitial may not have time to fire.

Instead you should call `showInterstitial()` at a natural break point in your app.

NB You can test that your interstitials are working by adding a button that shows the interstitial when you press it. Just remember to call `interstitial.load()` after showing to receive a new interstitial.